Preserve the column names when selecting part of the columns?
I have a table
CREATE TABLE policyholder(policyholder_id text, fname text, lname text, risk_score text, high_risk text);
INSERT INTO policyholder VALUES
('PH3068','ADAM','OCHSENBEIN','88','1'),
('PH3069','MALINDA','MEHSERLE','42','0'),
('PH3070','SANDRA','KUHTA','20','0');

and I want to get a table AS
CREATE TABLE mod(id text, others text);

INSERT INTO mod
SELECT policyholder_id, row_to_json(row(fname, lname, risk_score, high_risk)) from policyholder;

i.e., one column as id, and others as json.
However, we have
 policyholder_id |                     row_to_json                     
-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 PH3068          | {"f1":"ADAM","f2":"OCHSENBEIN","f3":"88","f4":"1"}
 PH3069          | {"f1":"MALINDA","f2":"MEHSERLE","f3":"42","f4":"0"}
 PH3070          | {"f1":"SANDRA","f2":"KUHTA","f3":"20","f4":"0"}

bcuz the ROW() drops column name. But actually I want something like
{"fname": "ADAM", "lname" : "OCHSENBEIN","risk_score":"88","high_risk":"1"}

I don't want to create a new type because there is too much of this function.
I notice a similar question How to create a row without losing the column names, for input of row_to_json?
However, I failed to figure out how to apply it to this situation...

You are doing row_to_json so why are you storing the result in a text field instead of a json field?

I found an existing answer at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110613/create-smaller-row-from-alias-and-preserve-column-names
and I got
SELECT policyholder_id, row_to_json((select x from (select fname, lname, risk_score, high_risk) x)) from policyholder;
 policyholder_id |                               row_to_json                                
-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PH3068          | {"fname":"ADAM","lname":"OCHSENBEIN","risk_score":"88","high_risk":"1"}
 PH3069          | {"fname":"MALINDA","lname":"MEHSERLE","risk_score":"42","high_risk":"0"}
 PH3070          | {"fname":"SANDRA","lname":"KUHTA","risk_score":"20","high_risk":"0"}
(3 rows)


The first version below is a partial solution.
The second version matches your desired result.
=# SELECT policyholder_id, row_to_json((p.*)) from policyholder AS p;
 policyholder_id |                                             row_to_json                                             
-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PH3068          | {"policyholder_id":"PH3068","fname":"ADAM","lname":"OCHSENBEIN","risk_score":"88","high_risk":"1"}
 PH3069          | {"policyholder_id":"PH3069","fname":"MALINDA","lname":"MEHSERLE","risk_score":"42","high_risk":"0"}
 PH3070          | {"policyholder_id":"PH3070","fname":"SANDRA","lname":"KUHTA","risk_score":"20","high_risk":"0"}
(3 rows)

Here is a version where I remove the policyholder_id value from the JSON. This seems to require casting as jsonb:
=# SELECT policyholder_id, row_to_json((p.*))::jsonb - 'policyholder_id' AS json FROM policyholder AS p;
 policyholder_id |                                      json                                       
-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PH3068          | {"fname": "ADAM", "lname": "OCHSENBEIN", "high_risk": "1", "risk_score": "88"}
 PH3069          | {"fname": "MALINDA", "lname": "MEHSERLE", "high_risk": "0", "risk_score": "42"}
 PH3070          | {"fname": "SANDRA", "lname": "KUHTA", "high_risk": "0", "risk_score": "20"}
(3 rows)


You can drop the row and strip extra fields from the json:
SELECT
  policyholder_id,
  jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_set(to_jsonb(row_to_json(p)), '{policyholder_id}', 'null')) 
FROM policyholder p;

Or build it from scratch:
SELECT
  policyholder_id,
  json_build_object('fname', fname, 'lname', lname, 'risk_score', risk_score, 'high_risk', high_risk)
FROM policyholder;

